# image upload in ckeditor 5 not working with laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

I am developing a website with Laravel 8 and JavaScript.
I use ckeditor 5 and it works fine. The problem occurs when I try to upload a photo. Photo upload is done but I get an error message and no photo is displayed. I get an error with the following title:
"Cannot upload file: filename.jpg"
I think I am not return the correct response to Frontend.
I have these codes in the **route/web.php** file

```
Route::group(["middleware"=>"auth","prefix"=>"panel"],function (){
    Route::post('/post/edit/{post_slug}', [PostController::class,"update"])->name("updatePostRoute");
    Route::get('/post/edit/{post_slug}', [RenderPanelController::class,"renderPostEditPage"])->name("renderPostEditPageRoute");
    Route::post('/post/ckeditor/upload', [PostController::class,"upload_image_cke"])->name('ckeditor.upload');
});
```

**in the PostController**

```
    public function upload_image_cke(Request $request){
        if ($request->hasFile('upload')) {
            $originName = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = pathinfo($originName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = $fileName . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;

            $request->file('upload')->move(public_path('media'), $fileName);

            $CKEditorFuncNum = $request->input('CKEditorFuncNum');
            $url = asset('media/' . $fileName);
            $msg = 'upload successfully';
            $response = "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url', '$msg')</script>";

            @header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
            echo $response;

        }
    }
```

in the blade file:

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="content" id="content"></textarea>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/27.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#content' ), {
            ckfinder: {
                uploadUrl: '{{route('ckeditor.upload')."?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json"}}',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
                }
            }
        },{
            alignment: {
                options: [ 'right', 'right' ]
            }} )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( editor );
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        })
</script>
```

**What response do I need to return for the photo upload to work correctly?**

Answer (score 8):

I have another way to do it. Hope it works for you and many devs.

My way of doing it defines a storage path dynamically for each user (`$path_url` variable)

Note that you must run `php artisan storage:link` on Terminal

**web.php**

```
Route::post('ckeditor/upload', 'App\Http\Controllers\CKEditorController@store')->name('ckeditor.upload');
```

**CKEditorController - Method store**

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {
      $path_url = 'storage/' . Auth::id();

      if ($request->hasFile('upload')) {
         $originName = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
         $fileName = pathinfo($originName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
         $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $fileName = Str::slug($fileName) . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
         $request->file('upload')->move(public_path($path_url), $fileName);
         $url = asset($path_url . '/' . $fileName);
      }

      return response()->json(['url' => $url]);
   }
```

**Form**

```
<textarea name="body" id="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Now, you must define an "Adapter" to upload the files to Storage

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/27.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    //Define an adapter to upload the files
    class MyUploadAdapter {
       constructor(loader) {
          // The file loader instance to use during the upload. It sounds scary but do not
          // worry — the loader will be passed into the adapter later on in this guide.
          this.loader = loader;

          // URL where to send files.
          this.url = '{{ route('ckeditor.upload') }}';

          //
       }
       // Starts the upload process.
       upload() {
          return this.loader.file.then(
             (file) =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                   this._initRequest();
                   this._initListeners(resolve, reject, file);
                   this._sendRequest(file);
                })
          );
       }
       // Aborts the upload process.
       abort() {
          if (this.xhr) {
             this.xhr.abort();
          }
       }
       // Initializes the XMLHttpRequest object using the URL passed to the constructor.
       _initRequest() {
          const xhr = (this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest());
          // Note that your request may look different. It is up to you and your editor
          // integration to choose the right communication channel. This example uses
          // a POST request with JSON as a data structure but your configuration
          // could be different.
          // xhr.open('POST', this.url, true);
          xhr.open("POST", this.url, true);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("x-csrf-token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
          xhr.responseType = "json";
       }
       // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
       _initListeners(resolve, reject, file) {
          const xhr = this.xhr;
          const loader = this.loader;
          const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${file.name}.`;
          xhr.addEventListener("error", () => reject(genericErrorText));
          xhr.addEventListener("abort", () => reject());
          xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
             const response = xhr.response;
             // This example assumes the XHR server's "response" object will come with
             // an "error" which has its own "message" that can be passed to reject()
             // in the upload promise.
             //
             // Your integration may handle upload errors in a different way so make sure
             // it is done properly. The reject() function must be called when the upload fails.
             if (!response || response.error) {
                return reject(response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText);
             }
             // If the upload is successful, resolve the upload promise with an object containing
             // at least the "default" URL, pointing to the image on the server.
             // This URL will be used to display the image in the content. Learn more in the
             // UploadAdapter#upload documentation.
             resolve({
                default: response.url,
             });
          });
          // Upload progress when it is supported. The file loader has the #uploadTotal and #uploaded
          // properties which are used e.g. to display the upload progress bar in the editor
          // user interface.
          if (xhr.upload) {
             xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (evt) => {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                   loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                   loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
             });
          }
       }
       // Prepares the data and sends the request.
       _sendRequest(file) {
          // Prepare the form data.
          const data = new FormData();
          data.append("upload", file);
          // Important note: This is the right place to implement security mechanisms
          // like authentication and CSRF protection. For instance, you can use
          // XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader() to set the request headers containing
          // the CSRF token generated earlier by your application.
          // Send the request.
          this.xhr.send(data);
       }
       // ...
    }

    function SimpleUploadAdapterPlugin(editor) {
       editor.plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
          // Configure the URL to the upload script in your back-end here!
          return new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
       };
    }

    //Initialize the ckeditor
    ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#body"), {
       extraPlugins: [SimpleUploadAdapterPlugin],
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
    });

</script>
```

I hope I've helped. A hug!

Comment: $url = Storage::url($request->file('upload')->store('public/uploads'));

Comment: Make sure to add use Str, use Auth and use Storage;

Answer (score 4):

**in the PostController**

```
public function upload_image_cke(Request $request){
    if ($request->hasFile('upload')) {
        $originName = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($originName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $fileName . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;

        $request->file('upload')->move(public_path('media'), $fileName);

        $url = asset('media/' . $fileName);
        return response()->json(['fileName' => $fileName, 'uploaded'=> 1, 'url' => $url]);
        

    }
}
```

**in the blade file:**

```
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#content' ), {
            ckfinder: {
                uploadUrl: '{{route('ckeditor.upload').'?_token='.csrf_token()}}'
            }
        },{
            alignment: {
                options: [ 'right', 'right' ]
            }} )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( editor );
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        })
</script>
```